# Struts 2 partial page submit and come to same page with retained values

Tags: java, struts2

I am working on struts 2 and I have the following scenario :-

(*) I have 3 dropdowns  in the page and I am selecting the values from first two dropdowns,  3rd dropdown gets populated from a popup page, the popup opens on click of a button and a value is added in popup page which gets inserted into db and then the popup closes and the parent action gets submitted and the drop down(3rd ) gets populated with values from db and above dropdown values (1st and 2nd) also stays, but
I am doing this using hidden input fields for each dropdown and passing value to action on partial submit and populating the form bean with values that I get from request object  in the action class itself. 
So, is this the correct approach?

(*)  To explain further the 3rd dropdown already has values and if needed the popup is opened and new value is added which should also reflect in that dropdown list.

Comment: Why do you use a popup, at all?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clearly telling the problem.

But as far as I understood, you can  use AJAX calls and use json sent through ajax to populate the fields in your action class and use them in your methods to sent the data to the server after applying your logic and populate the dropdowns after the change.

For more specific answer, you need to be clear in telling your doubt